# Recover firefox blocked downloads after clearing downloads list

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download

I used Firefox to downloaded a `.rar` file which is considered containing a virus or spyware.

> Blocked: May contain a virus or spyware

I've checked the `C:\Users\User\Downloads` and I see the file there, but then I accidentally cleaned the download list by clicking the `Clear Downloads` button.

I go back to the `Downloads` folder, and now the file is gone. The file size is quite large and it'll take a lot of efforts downloading the file again. So I'm wondering that can I retrieve the file back? Maybe from the `Temp` folder or somewhere?

**Update**

This question is different from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/898716/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-blocked-firefox-download). Since that question is about unblocking the blocked files, and mine is about how to recover it.

Comment: Check [this](http://superuser.com/a/901384/270195) post for details and don't forget to read the comment

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like but i can open the file after downloading, I think it's the `Clean Downloads` button which caused the file deleted.

Comment: `Clear downloads` ? or `Clean Downloads` ?

Comment: `Clear downloads`

Comment: `Clears downloads` doesn't delete files. It just empties the downloads list. Something else has deleted the file.

Comment: @DavidPostill Since firefox assumes it to be a virus or spyware, I think it's possible for firefox to delete the file while clearing the downloads without unblocking the file in advance.

Comment: Firefox already deleted the file before you cleared the download list.  If you had pressed <f5> (refresh) in `C:\Users\User\Downloads` you would see it already had been deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to recover a blocked Firefox download?](http://superuser.com/questions/898716/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-blocked-firefox-download)

Comment: @DavidPostill No, the `.part` file is still there.

Comment: The `.part` file is exactly that - part of the full download - it is of no help retrieving the file. All that shows is that Firefox **did not complete the download** so there is nothing to recover.

Comment: The other question clearly states in the answer that recovery is not possible (**In Firefox case, it will just delete the file, so it is no longer recoverable**) so it does answer this question and is a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidPostill After re-downloading the file again, I found out that after finish downloading the file, it shows the warning message and there's a `.part` file in the `Dwonloads` folder. After I unblocked the file, it turns to `.rar` as it should be. So Firefox **did completed the download**, and the `.part` extension is just a protection. So this question is not a duplicate, since I've seen that question before I ask. That question's answer is to unblock the file, which is in contrast with mine.

Comment: And it seems that clearing the download list without unblocking the file in advance will cause Firefox to delete the `.part` file (Blocked file is treated as download failure). And the file will be gone. `Recuva` can't recover the file either, so the only solution is to redownload the file again.

Comment: As long as the download-process isn't finished a file gets the .part extension appended - this is the expected behaviour in Firefox. Part of the download process is to check the file, if the check fails the download is not completed. Try unplugging your ethernet cable partway though a download. You will have a .part file.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes you're totally right! The blocked download acts the same, seems like Firefox assumes that the blocked download isn't a successful download. I think that appending the `.part` file in this case is to make sure the user know it's a blocked file. And then user can unblock the downloads if they think the file is safe.